# How to change Sampler name in Jmeter results output

Tags: jmeter

I added a Java Request Sampler to one of my test, but  Jmeter doesn't differentiate between samplers if they are non-http samplers, for example, BeanShell sampler also is logged with the name "sampler" as listed below.  Is there a way to customize this in jmeter so that i can specify the name sampler in the results.xml/output.

I have looked for this in the jmeter documentation, but did not find a way to configure it.

Java Request Sampler:

```
<sample t="1755" lt="0" ts="1301026564783" s="true" lb="get Connections for Current User" rc="200" rm="Total connections fetched: 30" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="" by="0"/>
<sample t="1980" lt="0" ts="1301026564640" s="true" lb="get Connections for Current User" rc="200" rm="Total connections fetched: 248" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="" by="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This easily handled with Listener scope - a place in Test Plan where you put your Simple Data Writer, Aggregate Report etc.

The simpliest case is to attach listener as child of sampler. This will cause listener to listen only to this sampler.